# Show $\sum_{i=1}^\infty 1/2^i-1/(2i-1)$ diverges

Tags: sequences-and-series

I want to show $\sum_{i=1}^\infty  -\frac{1}{2^i}+\frac{1}{2i-1}$ diverges. I consider the partial sums $s_n = \sum_{i=1}^n -\frac{1}{2^i}+\frac{1}{2i-1}$ and note that it is greater than $t_n=\sum_{i=1}^n -\frac{1}{2^i}+ \frac12\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{i}\geq 0$. Since  $\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{i}$ goes to infinity and $\sum_{i=1}^n -\frac{1}{2^i}$ to $-1$, $t_n\to \infty$ and by comparison also $s_n$ diverges. Is the argument valid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Is the argument valid?*

Yes.

We have that the partial sum of the given series satisfies, as $N \to \infty$,
$$
\sum_{i=1}^N\left( -\frac{1}{2^i}+\frac{1}{2i-1}\right)=-1+\frac{1}{2^N}+\sum_{i=1}^N\frac{1}{2i-1}\ge -1+\frac12\sum_{i=1}^N\frac{1}{i}
$$
and the latter sequence tends classically to $\infty$.

Answer (score 0):

Actually $\sum_{i  =1 }^{\infty}(-\frac{1}{2^{i}} + \frac{1}{2i - 1}) = S_{1} + S_{2}$,where $S_{1} = -\sum_{i = 1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2^{i}}$ and $S_{2 } = \frac{1}{2i - 1}$ , now we observe that since $S_{1}$ is a geometric series it converges to a finite value and next we observe that $S_{2}$ is of the form $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n}$ which we know diverges so the series is actually the sum of a value and a series which diverges so the net sum series diverges!

Hope this helps.